# Inner join of 3 tables giving repeated results

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have following 3 Table structure(not mentioned allcolumns ,only required)

**user_master**

> user_id (primary key)
>
> fname

**employee**

> employee_id (primary key)
>
> user_id (foreign key)
>
> estate

**studexperience_master**

> exp_id (primary key)
>
> user_id (foreign key)

I have following 2 mysql queries,fetching data from 3 tables and while displaying on form displayin in 1 table (following queries are for search result)  .first two tables are getting joined properly but Problem is that while joining next two table (i.e employee and studexperience_master) data is fetched repeated if same user_id is there say for 3 times than getttin 3 rows in $result set which should be only 1 row ,I tried `DISTINCT ALSO FOR SECOND INNER JOIN BUT ISSUE NOT GETTING SOLVE ,HOW THE QUERY SHOULD BE?`

```
$get_work=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT wm.work,wm.status FROM user_master um 
INNER JOIN employee emp ON um.user_id =emp.user_id 
INNER JOIN studexperience_master wm 
ON emp.user_id=wm.user_id 
WHERE wm.display='Y' $status_val $company_val $searchkind_val $location_val 
$search_Qualification_val");
```

---

```
        SELECT um.user_id,
       um.fname,
       um.lname,
       um.email,
       um.mobile,
       emp.employee_id,
       emp.ecountry,
       emp.estate,
       emp.ecity,
       emp.prefcities,
       emp.ca,
       emp.cs,
       emp.cwa,
       emp.completed,
       emp.persuing
FROM user_master um
INNER JOIN employee emp 
ON um.user_id =emp.user_id
INNER JOIN studexperience_master wm 
ON emp.user_id=wm.user_id
WHERE wm.display='Y' $status_val 
$company_val $searchkind_val $location_val 
$search_Qualification_val
```

and where clause values belong to values like this

```
WHERE wm.display='Y' AND status LIKE '%Fresher%' AND efamiliar LIKE '%Tally %' AND work LIKE 'Excise Audit' AND ecountry LIKE 'pune' OR ecity LIKE 'pune' OR estate LIKE 'pune' OR prefcities LIKE 'pune' AND ca REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR cs REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR cwa REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR completed REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR persuing REGEXP '%|CA CPT%'
```

[image: I have two user in user master and there respective work in third table ,Now for monika there are 2 rows and for dinesh 3 rows (in third table) so getting total 5 rows which should be only 2 and also in last column I am getting displayed all work of "work column" in table ,which should be only respective works of particular user]

**user_master**

> user_id- 2
>
> fname- monika
>
> mobile- 2147...
>
> email- a@a.b

**employee**

```
   >employee_id- 1

    >user_id- 2

    >ecity- Amravati

    >ca- CA IPCC Appeared

    >cs- CS Executive Appeared

    >cwa- CWA Inter Appeared
```

**studexperience_master**

ROW1

> exp_id-1
>
> user_id- 2
>
> work- Tax AUDIT

ROW2

> exp_id-2
>
> user_id- 2
>
> work- VAT AUDIT

Comment: @morissette, No, group by is not a solution at all.

Comment: @morissette group by is giving unique rows but bcause of this my first query result getting **Displayed wrong** yes Rahul is right group by is not solution

Comment: @Durga: As multiple rows are coming in some table for same employee so we can help if you show your sample data of all 3 tables (specially for the user where you are getting duplicity), what is you getting by your query and what really you want.

Comment: Problem seems in employee table, first you need to get single row from employee table in a sub-query then join that to other tables or put a condition on employee table to get unique results.

Comment: @ZafarMalik can you please show how to do it ,I have added screenshot of search result in table

Comment: Your query is showing different columns and screen shot of report different. I can check if you provide complete details.

Comment: @ZafarMalik  I have added code of displaying data in table

Comment: I am not getting fields in your report screen shot and fields in query...It will be better just use your problematic query and share rough data by this query. you can share just for single employee where you are getting duplicity but all columns data (those columns are in query) should be there.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I have shown added data as in table please check the edit

Comment: @Durga: Dear, till I don't have fetched data by your query. As without knowing by which column value you are getting duplicty, I can't help.

Comment: @ZafarMalik I tell you simply when user get registered ,data is getting added in 3 table ,first two table will have unique rows added ,in third table multiple rows can be added for that unique user ,Now How should be my query so that while searching i should get distinct user displayed, I hope You get it now

Comment: @morissette you were right it worked by group by user_id

Comment: sounds like I deserve some points lol

Answer (score 0):

Just change your both query like below

Instead of joining with `emp.user_id` join with `um.user_id` cause it's PK and should be having unique data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT wm.work,wm.status  
FROM user_master um  
INNER JOIN employee emp  
ON um.user_id =emp.user_id  
INNER JOIN studexperience_master wm  
ON um.user_id=wm.user_id and wm.display='Y'
```

Second Query like

```
   SELECT um.user_id,
   um.fname,
   um.lname,
   um.email,
   um.mobile,
   emp.employee_id,
   emp.ecountry,
   emp.estate,
   emp.ecity,
   emp.prefcities,
   emp.ca,
   emp.cs,
   emp.cwa,
   emp.completed,
   emp.persuing
FROM user_master um
INNER JOIN employee emp 
ON um.user_id =emp.user_id
INNER JOIN studexperience_master wm 
ON um.user_id=wm.user_id and wm.display='Y'
```

Though I am not able to understand in your `where` what those variables means? Your `where` looks weird to me.

```
WHERE wm.display='Y' $status_val $company_val $searchkind_val $location_val 
$search_Qualification_val
```

Comment: No this thing doesn't solves issue bcause even in employee table I am having unique values for user_id , i have mention where clause values in question edit

Comment: @Durga, provide your table schema (not entire but those columns included in query) and some sample data. can take a look then.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT distinct um.user_id,
       um.fname,
       um.lname,
       um.email,
       um.mobile,
       emp.employee_id,
       emp.ecountry,
       emp.estate,
       emp.ecity,
       emp.prefcities,
       emp.ca,
       emp.cs,
       emp.cwa,
       emp.completed,
       emp.persuing
FROM user_master um
INNER JOIN employee emp 
ON um.user_id =emp.user_id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM studexperience_master WHERE <your ALL conditions ON this TABLE>) wm 
ON emp.user_id=wm.user_id
WHERE $status_val 
$company_val $searchkind_val $location_val 
$search_Qualification_val;
```

Comment: No its not working ,Query itself not getting executed ,giving error "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Comment: due to this reason complete information is required..please check following (status LIKE '%Fresher%' AND efamiliar LIKE '%Tally %' AND work LIKE 'Excise Audit' AND ecountry LIKE 'pune' OR ecity LIKE 'pune' OR estate LIKE 'pune' OR prefcities LIKE 'pune' AND ca REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR cs REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR cwa REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR completed REGEXP '%|CA CPT%' OR persuing REGEXP '%|CA CPT%') columns should not belong to studexperience_master table and you are passing all parameters or not....for safe side first you check simple queries with values then you can try with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Can u try Something like this. If Student experienc master table is having duplicates then just try to take top one record(based on some conditions you can do filtters for this records as your wish).

```
Select * from user_master UM
inner join employee EMP on UM.UserId = EMP.UserId
inner join studexperience_master USM on EMP.UserId = (SELECT  TOP 1 UserId FROM studexperience_master RJK WHERE USM.UserId = RJK.UserId)
```

Let me know if any probs or need any help., :)